# Exception has occurred. FlutterError (MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery

Tags: flutter, dart

Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you do not have a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.
The context used was:
Scaffold)

I got this error can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: Please provide a code sample

Comment: which sample you need?

Comment: Your code where the MediaQuery.of() is called for example

Comment: Here is the error in the line               void main() => runApp(MyApp());

Comment: Change this line with 
void main() {runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()))}
You need to have a MaterialApp to call MediaQuery.of()

Comment: I got it thnx sir

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your app starts with any kind of app: `MaterialApp`, `WidgetsApp` or `CupertinoApp`, that's where the `MediaQuery` inherited widget is created.

```
void main() {
 runApp(
  MaterialApp(
   home: MyWidget()
  )
 )
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQuery.of(context); // You can access it here.
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: sir i need help personally can u help me? What i need to solve this issue as i didn't understand what you mean to say